# BSPs, Octrees and modern graphics hardware

Tags: 3d, graphics

I have read a lot of literature on BSPs, Octrees and like. Problem is that it is all old literature from software rendering time. Nobody describes how it is implemented today. So here is my idea how to do it and my question.

Let's say that I use some partitioning algorithm, it does not matter which one. I subdivide my level mesh into multiple partitions and store it in RAM. Should I simply create vertex buffers for each node so I can render my scene faster or what?

How do you do it, is there any better way today?

Thank you

Comment: Rendering systems (hardware vs software) and spatial partitioning are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: Basically I do not want to render entire level mesh at once, I want  to render one part at a time (of course visible parts) so I can render faster. I don't think that these systems are orthogonal because one delivers data to other.

Comment: They remain orthogonal; just because in a particular (and indeed, common case) a partitioning system and a render system may communicate, they are simply doing so via some interface. The implementations behind those interfaces remain independent.

Comment: You're mixing up how to determine *what* you want to draw with *how* that data makes it to the screen. BSPs and other partitioning methods are equally valid, and typically identically implemented, regardless of what type of renderer is being used.